# Null of .getElementById() in the Function

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Maybe it's stupid, but I can not understand what is wrong with the input arguments transfering in the function `children`.

I'm trying to send in the function `children` the Id of the elements in DOM - `table` and `ol` and then output these elements in `console.log`.

```
<body>

<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<ol id="ol">
  <li>11</li>
  <li>22</li>
  <li>33</li>
  <li>44</li>
</ol>

<script>

    function children(elem) { 

        var idElements = document.getElementById('elem');
        console.log(idElements); // result - "null"

    }

    children(table); // get DOM element with id="table"
    children(ol); // get DOM element with id="ol"

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: You have to remove quotes, sine it makes it not variable but value. And pass to function string, not just text, because JS considers this as a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function children(elem) { 
    var idElements = document.getElementById(elem);//remove ("") around elem variable

    console.log(idElements);

}
 //watch the quotations: send them AS STRINGS 
children("table"); // get DOM element with id="table"
children("ol"); // get DOM element with id="ol"
```

Comment: No, we can not modify input argument values

Comment: @SviatKuzhelev the code you have shown has to be change as described in this answer. The quotes have to be removed around `elem`  otherwise you will always search for `#elem`, and the varibales `table`  and `ol`  are not defined in your question. If you cannot modify the input arguments, then you have to update your question to be more complete.

Comment: can you clarify what tou mean by " not modify input argument values " ?

Answer (score 0):

You are currently not passing anything to the children function as both table and ol will be undefined (you are passing them as undefined variables), pass them as strings instead. Furthermore, the children function's argument `elem` is never used - it should be passed to the `getElementById` method.

```
function children(elem) { 

    var idElements = document.getElementById(elem);
    console.log(idElements);

}

children('table'); // get DOM element with id="table"
children('ol'); // get DOM element with id="ol"
```